# X-axis label cutoff in subplot

Tags: matlab, label, scilab, subplot

I have a vertical subplot of three plots. All three have different titles and y-labels. However, they have the same x-label. The graphic window cuts off the last x-label so it is not visible even when exporting to jpeg. How do I make it so that the last x-label appears? I am using Scilab, but matlab help would be welcomed.

```
subplot(3,1,3)
plot(time,zCorr,"color","blue")
title('Change in z-coordinate correction over time','color','black','fontsize',3)
xlabel("time(s)","color", "black", "fontsize", 3)
ylabel("z-correction(m)","color", "black","fontsize", 3 )
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code in MATLAB will save a jpeg with x-label visible on the third plot:

> > s1 = subplot(3,1,3);
> >
> > xlabel(s1, 'Something')
> >
> > saveas(gcf, 'Something', 'jpg')

So I'm afraid the problem is not reproducible in MATLAB.

Comment: I have the same code. The problem lies in the graphic window when the plots are displayed. If i were to show the same xlabel for all three plots then only the top two plots would show the label. The last xlabel is simply cutoff.

Comment: please edit into your question the shortest relevant part of the code and an image of whats happening.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't post an image of whats happening. I have shown the code for the last subplot in the question.

Comment: replace subplot command with "axhandle = subplot(3,1,3)" and xlabel command with "xlabel(axhandle  "time(s)","color", "black", "fontsize", 3)".